# Convert a video with a specific subtitle overlay

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, subtitles, overlay

I downloaded a [video file](https://py.tedcdn.com/consus/projects/00/45/63/001/products/downloads/2012e-jane-hirshfield-metaphor-001-f73ea77d-e0d7-4f18-9d9c-1a74fb80d2d9-download-5000k.mp4) found on [TED](https://www.ted.com/talks/jane_hirshfield_the_art_of_the_metaphor?language=en). It was with subtitles in different languages. Then I tried to convert it to an MP4 file using the [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org). In the conversion profile, I checked **Overlay subtitles on the video**. How can I choose a specific language, for example English, as a subtitle to overlay the video I convert?

Comment: That depend on the specific software you're using for the conversion and didn't mention.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Sorry, I just edited the question.

Comment: VLC is a jack of all trades and very good in some of them but its conversion feature is poor and barebones. I suggest you use something like Handbrake. VLC can't do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it appears you're not going to get what you want out of VLC in its current state. There is free open source software that can handle this very easily, though - [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/).

The UI may look complicated but what you want can be done in 30 seconds. Click on "Source" in the top left and pick your video. Then select `General > Fast 1080p30` in the Preset dropdown that is a little below the Source button (or go to the "Video" tab and select your options more finely).

Then go to Subtitles. There will be a "Foreign Audio Scan" subtitles you can delete if you want. Then click "Add" and choose `14.English`. You have the option of standard subtitles or "burning them in" to the video.

[image: Handbrake visualization]

You can then press "Start" to begin encoding. Note the outgoing filename at the bottom of the window. The `m4v` extension is not really different from `mp4` and is essentially interchangeable. It just allows more compatibility with certain Apple devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are many products that can do what you ask. Here is one
such method.

- Download the free
  [XviD4PSP](https://www.videohelp.com/software/XviD4PSP)
  and extract the `.exe` from the Zip archive
  (no installation required)
- Run XviD4PSP
- Open your video
- In the Streams tab, look for English
- Click the drop-down list next to "Codec:" and select "HARDSUB"
- On top, ensure the "Container:" is MP4
- Click Start
- The newly encoded file will be found in the source folder with
  the string "_encoded" appended to its name.

The result file will not have any subtitle file, and the English
text will be hard-coded inside the video.

---

*(This is the official answer for VLC, which does not work at the moment)*

There is a very highly upvoted post
[How can I make VLC auto-select subtitles in an MKV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/836592/how-can-i-make-vlc-auto-select-subtitles-in-an-mkv-file)

The basic method, compiled from more than one answer, is:

- Start playing the video in VLC
- Examine the Media Info in menu *Tools > Media information* (or CTRL+J),
  tab Codec
- Find your stream (normally the first streams are for video and audio)
  and note down its ID and language
- Use Ctrl+P to open Preferences
- Select "All" settings in the bottom left
- Select "Input/Codecs"
- Change "Subtitle track ID" to the steam number. You may also
  set "Subtitle language" to the language (it's unclear which setting
  is really determinant here) and click Save
- Transcode the video
- Undo your changes in Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work for me. It made no changes. I wonder if you have tried this method on my video file.

Comment: I tried it now, and VLC just hardcodes the first subtitle only. This is evidently a bug that merits being a bug-report, but I'll add another option to my answer (and try it on your video).

Answer (score 0):

At first choose the subtitle language e.g. in the menu bar via the Subtitle menu at position #5 after Media, Playback, Audio, Video. For example "Subtitle -> Sub Track -> Track 14 - [English]".

[image: VLC subtitle selection]

Then open the "Convert / Save" dialog, click through to "Edit selected profile" where in the "Video codec" tab make sure to uncheck  "Keep original video track".

[image: Uncheck 'Keep original video track' dialog]

Comment: I tried it to no success.

Comment: What does no success mean? No converted mp4 file, converted file without subtitles or with subtitles in another language?

Comment: With subtitles in another language. It always converts with the first sub track, Gallegan, I guess.

Comment: Which version of Windows and VLC are you at? For me it works on Win 10 22H2 and VLC 3.0.19. Does it add Gallegan subtitles (1st one: _Translator: M. Carmen Losada_) even when English ones are displaying in the running video as in my screenshot?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 22H2, VLC 3.0.20. "Does it add Gallegan subtitles (1st one: Translator: M. Carmen Losada) even when English ones are displaying in the running video as in my screenshot?" No, it doesn't happen when you play the original video file: It happens after conversion.

Comment: Does it happen when you play the original file _with English subtitles_ and then with the video playing start the conversion dialog?

Comment: It happens when I play the converted file. I was wondering if you'd mind making a screencast of the steps you take. I follow your instructions, but don't get the same result as you do. 

Comment: I only converted the first six seconds and when I read _Translator: ..._ I thought it was English when in fact it was Gallegan. Sorry. There seems to be [a history](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=147589) with subtitle difficulties in VLC. The *sub-track* and *sub-track-id* options apparently don't work with [tx3g/MPEG-4 Timed Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_17) subtitles - only with DVDs. The log says `mp4 debug: adding track[Id 0x3] subtitle (enable) language glg`  and later `adding track[Id 0x10] subtitle (disable) language eng` .